# is it possible to go with the babies (Italian passport holders) but leave them in Brazil for a month or two?

Tags: children, italian-citizens, italy-aire

I and my wife have 3 children, the boy is 5 years old and 2 girls, 1 year old.

We live in London (UK).
The nursery fees are very high and my wife wants to go back to work.
There are other things as well, that I rather not mention, but they are not directly related to this question.

As one possible solution we are considering to travel to Brazil, where my mother and my sister live, and leave the 2 girls there for a month.

Question:

If I buy a return ticket and then on the way back I don't show up with the babies, would that be a problem?

Clarification:

*the plan is:*

1. I, with my wife and 3 kids go to brazil in december
2. I, with my wife and the 5 years old boy come back to UK in January - the 2 babies remain in Brazil
3. in march I go alone to Brazil, and bring back my mother and the 2 babies
4. after some time in London, my mother returns to Brazil
5. All are Italian citizens registered in the [AIRE](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/aire_0.html) system

Comment: Did you consider nested tickets. UK to Brazil and return with a two months stay for you and the kids, and Brazil - UK and return just for you within that period?

Comment: @Willeke thank you, I have added some clarification now

Comment: @MarkJohnson why?  Its a question about whether one year old twins can spend a month with their grandmother in Brazil.

Comment: @phoog It is also a temporary change of residence and child custodianship outside the home country. For Italians the AIRE system is involved, for which **expatriates** would be more appropriate.

Comment: There will probably be transition arrangements even if this happens after Brexit, but one complication is that I think you are relying on EU freedom of movement to let the grandmother babysit in the UK without a work visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult question, with no simple answer.

It is also a question that belongs in

- **expatriates.stackexchange.com**

---

**Assumptions**: All participants

- parents, children, mother and sister

are Italian citizens.

All Italians living outside of Italy are **required** to register themselves with the [AIRE](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/aire_0.html) system

- if this is **not** the case, do so before leaving the United Kingdom

Once in Brazil register the children at the residence of your mother and/or sister

- the children will have their own [passports](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/documenti_di_viaggio/passaporto.html)

This should insure, should questions arise, that no misunderstandings of your intentions are made.

Consultation with the Italian Embassy or Consulate is **strongly** advised to insure that everything is being dealt with in a transparent manner.

---

**Sources**:

- **[Anagrafe Italiani Residenti Estero](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/aire_0.html)** (AIRE).
- [Italy - Passaport](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/documenti_di_viaggio/passaporto.html)

Comment: the assumptions are correct and we are all registered in the [AIRE](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/aire_0.html) very good points

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli The last being the most important (Theory and Praxis). Please report back with the results of such a consultation.

Comment: if I actually go and do this, I will certainly add the feedback as I did [on this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/118738/20586)

Comment: On an additional note, you also have to consult a lawyer in Brazil to make sure the appropriate procedures for custody are done. I indeed agree that it belongs in Expats SE, it is much more complex than "vacations with grandma"